# NPM global package install not working properly

Tags: npm

Tearing my hair out over this.

I used to have a npm package called 'eleventy' installed globaly and working on my laptop. Today I find this: `fish: Unknown command 'eleventy'`

Tried this `npm install -g eleventy` and got this

```
+ eleventy@0.2.0
updated 1 package in 0.289s
```

Things tried from other posted questions:

`npm get prefix` outputs `/usr/local`

`ls /usr/local/lib/node_modules/` outputs `eleventy npm`

but not `eleventy` found in `/usr/local/bin`

`echo $PATH` = `/usr/local/php5/bin/ /usr/local/bin /usr/local/lib /usr/bin /bin /usr/sbin /sbin`

Tried reinstalling npm and nodejs as well but no luck so far. Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, looks like I'm an idiot. I was installing the wrong package with a similar name.

I needed to use

`npm install -g @11ty/eleventy`